# pmd:UseConcurrentHashMap not working?

Tags: java, android, sonarqube, pmd

I've analysed my Android project using rules from PMD and I see this:

[image: pmd:UseConcurrentHashMap-bug]

What's the problem?

**Source code:** Java 1.7 (Android)

**SonarQube:** version 4.5.4 LTS with PMD plugin 2.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is resolved by PMD in version 5.3.2, however the Sonar PMD Plugin latest version is [2.4.1](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/PMD+Plugin) (which corresponds to PMD 5.3.1) for SonarQube 4.5.4.

You'll probably have to wait until a new Sonar PMD Plugin is released for the fix.

```
PMD Plugin  2.0  2.1  2.2    2.3    2.4.1
PMD         4.3  4.3  5.1.1  5.2.1  5.3.1
```

PMD bug fix:
http://sourceforge.net/p/pmd/bugs/1342/

You can disable the rule for now until the PMD Plugin is updated with the fix from PMD 5.3.2.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer :)